# React Native - Splash Screen Error ( cannot find symbol ) in MainActivity

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-activity, react-native-splash-screen

I try to add Splash Screen to my React Native Project. 
I use this npm package "**react-native-splash-screen**". 
According to this npm package, I change the **MainActivity.java** file to:

```
//splash screen
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  // splash screen
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "ABC";
  }

  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
        this,
        getMainComponentName(),
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled());
  }
}
```

So, this gives me an error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                          ^
  symbol:   class Bundle
  location: class MainActivity
```

Comment: Question needs formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `import android.os.Bundle;` on the top of MainActivity.java file

```
import android.os.Bundle; // <- Add this line
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
...
```